# Git server in jail: working directory in different jail

Tags: git, freebsd, jail

I'm setting up a FreeBSD server with five jails.
some of them are web server with web apps.
Some of those apps should be updated using git.

I was now thinking about running the git server in his own jail.

But would there be any way to keep the git server and the web apps in sync or would this solution just create overhead?

Comment: This is more a question for serverfault.com. Consider doing the git pull on the host system not inside the jail.

Comment: I might think about doing this, thanks @arved!

Comment: Why do you think you need to run a "git server"?

Comment: I would like to keep the web app jails updated via one single fit jail. Would there be another way I'm missing?